# Save XML file to HDFS

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have a XML string and it needs to be saved to HDFS location.

```
<transportation-carrier>
<SCAC>LKSKS</SCAC>
<name>JACKSONVILLE Name</name>
<billing-road-number>139</billing-road-number>
<effective-date>2017-03-08</effective-date>
<expiration-date>2017-03-07</expiration-date>
</transportation-carrier>
```

I tried to save this xml element in abc to a path in HDFS using the save command -

```
 scala.xml.XML.save("/data/temp/example.xml", abc)
```

I get this error message -

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \data\temp\example.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)**

I would appreciate help in saving the file to a HDFS path.

Comment: I am not sure if you are using SPARK here. If you are trying to write the file from a standalone Scala application, you can try checking https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Comment: I am using Spark to connect to the cluster.

Comment: I do not see any reference to Spark Context and RDD as such in your code. If you are using those things then you could do rdd.saveAsXXX APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up converting the string XML to a XML file and then converted this to file to a dataframe using databricks package for Scala

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Spark and Hadoop env, another way to do that is to use java.io and XML.write method instead of save.

It spares the need of an intermediary file:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{ FileSystem, Path, FSDataOutputStream }
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter

val xmlRoot : Elem = <myElem>test</myElem>
val path: Path = new Path("hdfs:///myfile.xml")
if (fs.exists(path)) {
   fs.delete(path, true)
}
val dataOutputStream: FSDataOutputStream = fs.create(path)
val bw: BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dataOutputStream, "UTF-8"))
XML.write(bw, xmlRoot, "utf-8", xmlDecl = true, doctype = null)
bw.close()
```

Works on a Cloudera + Zeppelin env.